# Understanding and different usage between libfuzzer and AFL

Tags: testing, fuzzing

I'm a noob to fuzz area and looked AFL implementation.

AFL seems to replace `stdin` file descriptor to `input file` descriptor. Whenever the target program encounters standard input, the target program takes input from the `input file`, not the `stdin`.

So, my question is popped from on this.

Let's say we made a library and we'd like to unit test to find some implementation bug using fuzzer. In this case, we don't take any `standard input`, just takes only function parameters from developers who use our library. Therefore, AFL doesn't work in this case.

`Libfuzzer` seems proper solution in this case since generated input can be fed into our specific interesting function.

Is this right understand? or does AFL also can work as `libfuzzer` for the unit test?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afl supports feeding inputs through files, not only `stdin`. To test a library that receives input through arguments, you can write a simple executable that will open an input file, read it's contents, call the needed library functions with argument values read from this file and close the file.